# Args cannot read proprety of undefined ("0")

Tags: discord, discord.js

So basically I have that command that use modals to create giveaways but there is one line bothering me. It is right under the `run: async` line. I have been trying to search the discord documentation about a change that happened from v13 to v14 (yes this code uses discord.js v1.14.5) but I have found nothing. The error is the following: `<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`. If you need anymore code, ask me (like the sub files or the rest of the code). Thanks in advance!

Code:

```js
        const {
          ChannelType,
          ButtonBuilder,
          ActionRowBuilder,
          ComponentType,
          TextInputStyle,
          TextInputBuilder,
          ModalBuilder,
          ButtonStyle,
          ApplicationCommandOptionType,
        } = require("discord.js");
        const ems = require("enhanced-ms");
        
        
        const start = require("./sub/start");
        const pause = require("./sub/pause");
        const resume = require("./sub/resume");
        const end = require("./sub/end");
        const reroll = require("./sub/reroll");
        const list = require("./sub/list");
        const edit = require("./sub/edit");
        
        module.exports = {
            name: "giveaway",
            description: "Start a giveaway!",
            type: 1,
            id: "Giveaway",
            options: [
              {
                name: "start",
                description: "start a giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "channel",
                    description: "the channel to start the giveaway in",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Channel,
                    channelTypes: [ChannelType.GuildText],
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: "pause",
                description: "pause a giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "message_id",
                    description: "the message id of the giveaway",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: "resume",
                description: "resume a paused giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "message_id",
                    description: "the message id of the giveaway",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: "end",
                description: "end a giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "message_id",
                    description: "the message id of the giveaway",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: "reroll",
                description: "reroll a giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "message_id",
                    description: "the message id of the giveaway",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: "list",
                description: "list all giveaways",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
              },
              {
                name: "edit",
                description: "edit a giveaway",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand,
                options: [
                  {
                    name: "message_id",
                    description: "the message id of the giveaway",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: true,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "add_duration",
                    description: "the number of minutes to add to the giveaway duration",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
                    required: false,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "new_prize",
                    description: "the new prize",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                    required: false,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "new_winners",
                    description: "the new number of winners",
                    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
                    required: false,
                  },
                ],
              },
           
            
            ],
           permissions: {
                DEFAULT_MEMBER_PERMISSIONS: "ManageMessages" // User permissions needed
        
          },
         /**
           * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
           */
            run: async (client, interaction, config, db, args, message) => {
            const sub = args[0]?.toLowerCase();
            //line above
            let response;
        
            //
            if (sub === "start") {
              if (!args[1]) return message.safeReply("Incorrect usage! Please provide a channel to start the giveaway in");
              const match = message.guild.findMatchingChannels(args[1]);
              if (!match.length) return message.safeReply(`No channel found matching ${args[1]}`);
              return await runModalSetup(message, match[0]);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "pause") {
              const messageId = args[1];
              response = await pause(message.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "resume") {
              const messageId = args[1];
              response = await resume(message.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "end") {
              const messageId = args[1];
              response = await end(message.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "reroll") {
              const messageId = args[1];
              response = await reroll(message.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "list") {
              response = await list(message.member);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "edit") {
              const messageId = args[1];
              if (!messageId) return message.safeReply("Incorrect usage! Please provide a message id");
              return await runModalEdit(message, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else response = "Not a valid sub command";
        
            await message.safeReply(response);
          },
        
          async interactionRun(interaction) {
            const sub = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
            let response;
        
            //
            if (sub === "start") {
              const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("channel");
              return await runModalSetup(interaction, channel);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "pause") {
              const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message_id");
              response = await pause(interaction.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "resume") {
              const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message_id");
              response = await resume(interaction.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "end") {
              const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message_id");
              response = await end(interaction.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "reroll") {
              const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message_id");
              response = await reroll(interaction.member, messageId);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "list") {
              response = await list(interaction.member);
            }
        
            //
            else if (sub === "edit") {
              const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message_id");
              const addDurationMs = ems(interaction.options.getInteger("add_duration"));
              if (!addDurationMs) {
                return interaction.followUp("Not a valid duration");
              }
              const newPrize = interaction.options.getString("new_prize");
              const newWinnerCount = interaction.options.getInteger("new_winners");
              response = await edit(interaction.member, messageId, addDurationMs, newPrize, newWinnerCount);
            }
        
            //
            else response = "Invalid subcommand";
        
            await interaction.followUp(response);
          },
        };
    
    //...
```

Command handler:

```js
const client = require("../index");
const { PermissionsBitField, Routes, REST, User } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const colors = require("colors");

module.exports = (client, config) => {
  console.log("0------------------| Application commands Handler:".blue);

  let commands = [];

  // Slash commands handler:
  fs.readdirSync('./commands/slash/').forEach((dir) => {
    console.log('[!] Started loading slash commands...'.yellow);
    const SlashCommands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/slash/${dir}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (let file of SlashCommands) {
      let pull = require(`../commands/slash/${dir}/${file}`);

      if (pull.name, pull.description, pull.type == 1) {
        client.slash_commands.set(pull.name, pull);
        console.log(`[HANDLER - SLASH] Loaded a file: ${pull.name} (#${client.slash_commands.size})`.brightGreen);

        commands.push({
          name: pull.name,
          description: pull.description,
          type: pull.type || 1,
          options: pull.options ? pull.options : null,
          default_permission: pull.permissions.DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS ? pull.permissions.DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS : null,
          default_member_permissions: pull.permissions.DEFAULT_MEMBER_PERMISSIONS ? PermissionsBitField.resolve(pull.permissions.DEFAULT_MEMBER_PERMISSIONS).toString() : null
        });

      } else {
        console.log(`[HANDLER - SLASH] Couldn't load the file ${file}, missing module name value, description, or type isn't 1.`.red)
        continue;
      };
    };
  });

  // User commands handler:
  fs.readdirSync('./commands/user/').forEach((dir) => {
    console.log('[!] Started loading user commands...'.yellow);
    const UserCommands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/user/${dir}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (let file of UserCommands) {
      let pull = require(`../commands/user/${dir}/${file}`);

      if (pull.name, pull.type == 2) {
        client.user_commands.set(pull.name, pull);
        console.log(`[HANDLER - USER] Loaded a file: ${pull.name} (#${client.user_commands.size})`.brightGreen);

        commands.push({
          name: pull.name,
          type: pull.type || 2,
        });

      } else {
        console.log(`[HANDLER - USER] Couldn't load the file ${file}, missing module name value or type isn't 2.`.red)
        continue;
      };
    };
  });

  // Message commands handler:
  fs.readdirSync('./commands/message/').forEach((dir) => {
    console.log('[!] Started loading message commands...'.yellow);
    const UserCommands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/message/${dir}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (let file of UserCommands) {
      let pull = require(`../commands/message/${dir}/${file}`);

      if (pull.name, pull.type == 3) {
        client.message_commands.set(pull.name, pull);
        console.log(`[HANDLER - MESSAGE] Loaded a file: ${pull.name} (#${client.user_commands.size})`.brightGreen);

        commands.push({
          name: pull.name,
          type: pull.type || 3,
        });

      } else {
        console.log(`[HANDLER - MESSAGE] Couldn't load the file ${file}, missing module name value or type isn't 2.`.red)
        continue;
      };
    };
  });

  // Registering all the application commands:
  if (!config.Client.ID) {
    console.log("[CRASH] You need to provide your bot ID in config.js!".red + "\n");
    return process.exit();
  };

  const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(config.Client.TOKEN || process.env.TOKEN);

  (async () => {
    console.log('[HANDLER] Started registering all the application commands.'.yellow);

    try {
      await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationCommands(config.Client.ID),
        { body: commands }
      );

      console.log('[HANDLER] Successfully registered all the application commands.'.brightGreen);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
};
```

InteractionCreate.js:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../../index");
const config = require("../../config/config.js");
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();

module.exports = {
  name: "interactionCreate"
};

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
    const command = client.slash_commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
      command.run(client, interaction, config, db);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    };
  };

  if (interaction.isUserContextMenuCommand()) { // User:
    const command = client.user_commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
      command.run(client, interaction, config, db);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    };
  };

  if (interaction.isMessageContextMenuCommand()) { // Message:
    const command = client.message_commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
      command.run(client, interaction, config, db);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    };
  };

  if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) { // Modals:
    const modal = client.modals.get(interaction.customId);

    if (!modal) return interaction.reply({
      embeds: [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setDescription('Something went wrong... Probably the Modal ID is not defined in the modals handler.')
          .setColor('Red')
      ],
      ephemeral: true
    });

    try {
      modal.run(client, interaction, config, db);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your command handler?

Comment: `args` is undefined so it's complaining because you're trying to access the element at index `0`. Try logging what `args` actually is.

Comment: @Cjmarkham I tried logging args and it did give me `undefined`. So I tried using `const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);` to define it but I get the following error `<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')`

Comment: That means that `content` is also undefined. How are you passing these values into the `run()` function?

Comment: @zmehall Yes but I actually have no idea how to define that, any ideas?

Comment: Where is your `interactionCreate` listener?

Comment: I think you should read the docs on how to use arguments in slash commands. In your command's file, you're taking the arguments `(client, interaction, config, db, args, message)`, but in the interactionCreate listener, you're passing in `(client, interaction, config, db)`. Args in slash commands use their own api. [Here](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html) are some examples.